# Find the frequency of a word in list with accordance to the first indexed item

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

Lets say I have a list like this

```
my_list = [(1, 'A'), (1, 'A'), (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (20, 'BB'), 
  (20, 'BB'), (100, 'CC'), (100, 'CC'), (100, 'CC')]
```

now i want to write a code in python 3 so that it returns the frequency of second element of item with accordance to the first item.
for example I expect the output to print something like below :

```
1: 3 (A), 1 : 1 (B), 20: 2(BB), 100: 3(CC)
```

Sorry for bad English. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Counter method from the Collections module.

```
from collections import Counter
my_list = [(1, 'A'), (1, 'A'), (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (20, 'BB'), 
  (20, 'BB'), (100, 'CC'), (100, 'CC'), (100, 'CC')]
print(Counter(my_list))
```

Output:

```
Counter({(1, 'A'): 3, (100, 'CC'): 3, (20, 'BB'): 2, (1, 'B'): 1})
```

Comment: I do not know why but when i try to use Counter as your suggestion i am getting this error    _count_elements(self, iterable)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'writeable void-scalar

Comment: Could you tell me what input you provided?

Comment: Counter doesn't work on non-hashable types like, colors = [['red', 'warm'], ['blue', 'cold'], ['red', 'warm']].

Comment: i figured it out tbanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Dict to achieve this instead of importing collections. Since, the items of your list are tuples, they can be used as keys of a dictionary.

Here's how you can do this:

```
list = [(1, 'A'), (1, 'A'), (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (20, 'BB'),  (20, 'BB'), (100, 'CC'), (100, 'CC'), (100, 'CC')]

dict = {}

for item in list:
    if item in dict:
        dict[item] += 1
    else:
        dict[item] = 1
print(dict)
```